# JLabel not showing up

Tags: java, swing, awt, jlabel

For some reason my `JLabel` isn't displaying and I can't figure out why
(*editString* DOES have a value).

```
compFrame.removeAll();
JPanel editPane = new JPanel();
editPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
compFrame.add(editPane);
//JLabel lastValue = new JLabel(editString);
editPane.add(new JLabel(editString));

compFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
compFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Why are using `compFrame.removeAll();`. Remove that line. It will work

Comment: I needed to clear it because I'm using it elsewhere. Didn't know I had to add getContentPane().

Comment: `compFrame.removeAll();` 1) Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). 2) In future, please post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use removeAll on ContentPane. Try this

```
compFrame.getContentPane().removeAll();
```

The API doc for removeAll says:

This method changes layout-related information, and therefore, invalidates the component hierarchy. If the container has already been displayed, the hierarchy must be validated thereafter in order to reflect the changes.

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much!